# automatic labeling a node with a text

Tags: c#, asp.net, syncfusion

Hi i would like after dropping my Symbols from Palette, that my symbol to be automatic labeled with Text.
Here is the Code:

```
protected void DiagramWebControl1_NodeDropFromPalette(object sender, Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Diagram.NodeDropFromPaletteEventArgs e)

{

   if (e.Node is PathNode || e.Node is Group)

   {

      PathNode node = e.Node as PathNode;

      if (node != null)

         node.Labels.Add(new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Label( node, node.Name));

      else

      {

        Group gnode = e.Node as Group;

        node.Labels.Add(new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Label (gnode, gnode.Name));

      }

  }

}
```

the problem is that every symbol (node) if its a PathNode or Group after the first dropping they are not labeled, after the second drop, third, etc.... from the same node, then they will be automatic labeled.
Need help!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the Syncfusion’s public forum regarding your requirement of adding label automatically to the node. Here's a [link](http://www.syncfusion.com/support/forums/general/107749/How-to-change-the-node-text).